# User login form redirect to base url

Tags: uri, migrations

Quick version:

The login form (at ?q=user/login) post it's information to www.domain.com when Drupal is at www.domain.com/sub/folder. Navigation URLs seem to work.

More info:

I'm in the process of migrating a drupal installation from a host to another. I've moved files/db on the new host, and I have a test url available that looks like

```
https://server.hostcompany.com:8443/sitepreview/http/mydomain.com/
```

I've set the RewriteBase (.htaccess) to

```
RewriteBase /sitepreview/http/mydomain.com
```

and the base url (settings) to

```
$base_url = 'https://server.host.com:8443/sitepreview/http/mydomain.com';
```

So I have this problem with the login form, making me unable to authentificate, and there are some images that are not loaded correctly (the sitepreview/http/mydomain.com is missing)

What have I forgotten/am I doing wrong?